# Checking if a folder is currently being used

Tags: qt, file-permissions

How can I check if a directory is currently being used in Qt? By "being used", I mean that a file in this folder is open (a .exe for example, as I am working on Windows).

I tried with QFileInfo::IsWritable() but it doesn't seem to work on directory, plus it's only to know if you can rename the file apparently (I tried this on my .exe and the result was true, even if my .exe was being... executed).

Any idea?

Comment: are you asking about checking if a file is open like a txt document or something, or specifically whether a process is running because you wont find that from the exe you need to check the process id

Comment: No, I am asking something specifically for folders. Like when you try to delete a folder but Windows tells you that it is not possible because the folder or one of its files is already open...

Comment: What about going through all files in the folder and checking it for them?

Comment: Checking what for them? I'm saying that either the .exe is running or not, `IsWritable` returns true, so what can I check? (it's basically the question I asked at the beginning...)